# Sequence of Integers that Returns Average at the End

Tags: java

Hey guys I need help with this assignment. When I run what I have it just loops forever, help would be much appreciated. Here's what my assignment is: 
Write a program segment on the following page which reads a sequence of integers from the keyboard until 0 (zero) is entered. As it is entered print each integer (except for the 0 that stops the program) and at the average of the integers entered.

1. Each non-zero integer is printed on a separate line.
2. this continues until a zero is read, at which point the segment stops.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class List {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int boom = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter a nonzero integer, please!");
        boom = keyboard.nextInt();
        while (boom != 0) {
            sum += boom;
            count++;
            average = ((double) sum) / count;
            System.out.println("The average is " + average);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to indent properly so that you (and we) can understand your code. Your `keyboard.nextInt()` line needs to be *inside* the loop, and then you need to fix up the loop logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read the keyboard input only once. That's what you should do:

```
while (boom=keyboard.nextInt() != 0) {   
    sum += boom;   
    count++;              
     average = ((double)sum) / count;  
    System.out.println ("The average is " + average);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will loop forever if you enter a non-zero integer at the `boom=keyboard.nextInt()` stage.   The reason why is that boom never changes in your while block and the condition for stopping is that boom does not equal zero.

You'll need to set boom to a non-zero value outside of the loop and move your assignment to boom of the int from the keyboard inside the loop.